# How fast does an alien grow in the Alien movies?

Tags: movie, alien-franchise

I just watched [*Alien*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078748) and when the alien leaves the host it's tiny.

A few minutes later in the movie they encounter the alien and it's now fully grown and is larger than a human.

I don't know how much time actually goes by in the movie but it couldn't be more then a few hours, it seems to grow extremely fast. How fast does it actually grow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Alien Wiki](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Xenomorph) "Maturity is reached in a few hours, and involves a dozenfold increase in mass..."

Given that it takes only a few hours to go from being face hugged to having one burst out of your chest, it looks like they can go from embryo to adult in only 6-8 hours.

Answer (score -1):

They grow from embryo to adult in about 2-3 hours max. However a queen may have taken 6-7 hours.

Comment: Can you cite a source or a timeline for that?  (Preferably a more canonical one than the wiki link in the above answer.)

Answer (score -3):

The alien in the first one was just a drone. Now if you are counting the time the facehugger was on there it might be at least 6-8 hours. But however the facehugger only needs an estimated 30-60 seconds to impregnate a host. But the xenomorph is growing inside the host. I was counting the amount of time outside the host. If I was counting time inside and outside the host it would be 6-8 hours.